# How do you interate over a Collection<T> and modify its items without ConcurrentModificationException?

Tags: java, iterator, collections, concurrentmodification

I need to do something like this...

```
Collection<T> myCollection; ///assume it is initialized and filled


for(Iterator<?> index = myCollection.iterator(); index.hasNext();)
{
    Object item = index.next();
    myCollection.remove(item);
}
```

Obviously this throws ConcurrentModificationException...

So I have tried this but doesn't does seem elegant/efficient and throws a Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to T warning

```
Object[] list = myCollection.toArray();
for(int index = list.length - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
 myCollection.remove((T)list[index]);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: Efficient Equivalent to Removing while Iterating a Collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/java-efficient-equivalent-to-removing-while-iterating-a-collection)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use [`iterator.remove()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove()):

```
for(Iterator<?> index = myCollection.iterator(); index.hasNext();)
{
    Object item = index.next();
    index.remove();
}
```

Beware that this may cause `O(n^2)` runtime for some datatypes (e.g. `ArrayList`).  In this particular case, it might be more efficient to simply clear the collection after the iteration.

Comment: well im actually using the command pattern so i cant use iterator remove.

Comment: oh thanks! i can ill just override that too. :) you put me on the right path thanks

Comment: Or copy the collection as you iterate.

Answer (score 0):

A side-caveat, the type of the original collection matters in this instance as well.  For instance, `Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3});` strangely creates an `UnmodifiableList`, in which case you would need to instantiate an empty ArrayList perform `newList.addAll(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3});`.